# Is possible to pull the table name in with query results? (PostgreSQL)

Tags: postgresql

We have a table sctructure that inherits its layout from a template

```
study_sample_template
```

When we create a new project, a study ID gets appended

```
study_sample_9810  
study_sample_9811
```

When I do a select *  on study_sample_template, it actually searches each individual table for results

QUESTION - I am pulling contact info such as first_name, last_name, state - can I also pull the table name so I know which project number its coming from?

query

```
select first_name, last_name, state
from study_sample_template
where state = 'VA'
```

Comment: Are you using table inheritance?

Comment: Check the tableoid: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-system-columns.html

Comment: Yes - just checked. Table inheritance. So I should grab the tableoid and join it with pgclass to pull in the name? Thanks @FrankHeikens

Comment: You can cast the tableoid directly to a regclass: SELECT tableoid::regclass, * FROM study_sample_template;